# How to free up memory on Array monitored by Angular2 change detection?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, typescript

For example I had a component contains a variable

`this.array = [];`

Then in the DOM I got a

`*ngFor="let el of array"` to loop displaying `Div`s on the DOM

The array content changes dynamically from 3000 elements to another 3000 elements, frequently, and let the change detection render to DOM.

Is this strategy to display dynamic data a good practice or is there any better way of saving memory usage?

[image]

Above picture showing the memory and call stack in three steps:

`before the array change script`
`during array change script running`
and
`changes happen on the dom`

Comment: It's hard to provide an answer without knowing the problem. Is it because you're rendering 3000 set of DOM elements? If so you'd need to find a solution to only render what's needed. Or is it because the change happens frequently and there's memory leak in the CD somewhere? If so you'd need to revise the CD Strategy.

Comment: @HarryNinh Initially the content scrolled smoothly with 3000 DOM, but after several Array updates, the scroll becomes laggy. I also used ngFor Fn trackedById, because only 1000 of the 3000 element will be replaced to new. This is not a production requirement, just from my interest.